# Spring security login except whitelisted IP

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring boot application and added Spring security. I would like that some ip ranges by pass the security while all other requests need to log in before. I have extended the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`as follows however it does not work as I would expect, The whitelisted IP can use the application without login while other requests get an HTTP 403 instead of getting the log in form. What I am doing wrong here?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().access("hasIpAddress('192.168.1.0/24') or isAuthenticated()");
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't configured form login, so there is nothing to redirect to and to add you also might need to add a custom failure handler to determine of one needs to redirect or not due to the additional rules. But I would start with configuring form login.

Comment: have a look here to configure your login [baeldung spring-security-login](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login)

Comment: Implement a filter something like `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` before login filter and from request get the remote address to verify weather its white listed..

Comment: Thanks..I just needed to add  ```.and().formLogin()```  as indicated by  M. Deinum